# Can listen on multiple ports and proxy_pass them to the same host in NGINX?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have the following config, which works but is very repetitive:

```
server {
  listen 8080;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://target_service:8080;
    proxy_set_header Host target_service;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Close";
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
  }
}

server {
  listen 8081;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://target_service:8081;
    proxy_set_header Host target_service;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Close";
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
  }
}
```

Is there a good way I can combine them into one `server` that listens to both ports, and forwards on the correct port for each request?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do that. Combine your server blocks:

```
server {
  listen 8080;
  listen 8081;
}
```

Then use the `$server_port` variable to create your desired url. You might need to specify a resolver as proxy_pass doesn't play nicely with dynamic variables, but this might get around that.

```
location / {
  set $target_url http://target_service:$server_port;
  proxy_pass $target_url;
  proxy_set_header Host target_service;
  proxy_set_header Connection "Close";
  proxy_http_version 1.1;
}
```